# Set the content of the textblock within toggle button

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to set the content of the textblock (as shown below) when the IsChecked property has changed for the toggle button. I have tried multiple ways but unable to get it to work.

```
<ToggleButton VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4 0 0 0" Background="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" Name="toggle">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=Foreground}">
            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_starwars_jedi}" />
            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        </Rectangle>
        <TextBlock x:Name="SimulationToggleButtonText" Margin="4 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Start Simulation">
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Content"  Value="Stop Simulation"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a control template, please see this adjusted code:

```
<ToggleButton VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4 0 0 0" Background="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" Name="toggle">
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=Foreground}">
                                <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                    <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_starwars_jedi}" />
                                </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="SimulationToggleButtonText" Margin="4 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Start Simulation">
                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="SimulationToggleButtonText" Property="Text" Value="Stop Simulation"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="SimulationToggleButtonText" Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

The problem is that your ToggleButton style doesn't have access to any controls that are a part of the ToggleButton content. By moving the controls and triggers to the template, they are in the same scope.

Comment: Great answer! but i have a small issue, the static resource icon under visual brush does not show up. what could be the reason. the resource icon are defined under the window.resource in the xaml file.

Comment: @Dilberted: That is likely a different issue. Perhaps you should try and reproduce some smaller code that reproduces this and ask a new question. What is `appbar_starwars_jedi`? Is it an object that derives from `Visual`?

Comment: it is defined in icons.xaml  <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Icons.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

Comment: i found the issue. in the rectangle i set the fill as {RelativeSource AncestorType=Button} instead of button it should be ToggleButton.